# Zipping Traversals

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a `Traversable` with holes in it -- imagine this binary tree:

```
         /       \
       /    \     Nothing
 Just 1    /  \  
    Nothing   Just 3
```

I also have a list of values to fill the holes with -- `[2, 4]` -- resulting in:

```
         /       \
       /    \     Just 4
 Just 1    /  \  
     Just 2   Just 3
```

I think it's possible to use a `lens` indexed traversal to traverse to the `Nothing`s and replace them with the value at the corresponding index from the list.

But it must be possible to do more directly without using indices?

Bonus points -- a few variations on this theme:

1. (my use case) The list of values must have *exactly* the same number of elements as holes in the traversal. Failure indicated with a `Maybe`.
2. The list must have *at least* as many elements, so we could have also passed in `[2, 4, 6]`, `[2, 4, ..]`, etc.
3. The list can have any number of elements, and we fill as many holes as we can with the elements we're given. This operation can't fail, it can just fill any number of holes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version which returns a `Left` if there are not enough elements.

You can fill the holes using `Traversable`'s `mapM` in the `State` monad:

```
 import qualified Data.Traversable as T
 import Control.Monad.State.Strict
 import Control.Error

 import qualified Data.Tree as Tree
 import Data.Tree (Tree(..))

 visit :: Maybe a -> ExceptT String (State [a]) a
 visit (Just x) = return x
 visit Nothing = do xs <- lift get
                    case xs of
                      (a:as) -> do lift (put as); return a
                      []     -> throwE "out of elements"

 fill :: T.Traversable t => t (Maybe a) -> [a] -> Either String (t a)
 fill t vals  = evalState (runExceptT (T.mapM visit t) ) vals

 tree = Node Nothing [ Node (Just "2") [], Node Nothing [] ]

 ex1 =  print $ fill tree ["a", "b", "c", "d" ] -- Right ...
 ex2 =  print $ fill tree ["a" ]                -- Left "out of elements"
```

If you want to make sure all the elements are used, change `fill` to:

```
fill :: T.Traversable t => t (Maybe a) -> [a] -> Either String (t a)
fill t vals = evalState (runExceptT doit) vals
  where doit = do t' <- T.mapM visit t
                  xs <- lift get
                  case xs of
                    [] -> return t'
                    _  -> throwE "not all elements were used"
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple (but partial) solution exploiting `mapAccumL`:

```
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

fill :: forall a t. T.Traversable t => t (Maybe a) -> [a] -> t a
fill t fillers = snd $ T.mapAccumL go fillers t
    where
      go :: [a] -> Maybe a -> ([a], a)
      go fs     (Just x) = (fs, x)
      go (f:fs) Nothing  = (fs, f)
      go []     Nothing  = error "not enough fillers!"
```

A total alternative:

```
fill2 :: forall a t. T.Traversable t => 
        t (Maybe a) -> [a] -> Maybe (t a)
fill2 t fillers  = sequenceA . snd $ T.mapAccumL go fillers t
    where
      go :: [a] -> Maybe a -> ([a], Maybe a)
      go (f:fs) Nothing  = (fs, Just f)
      go fs     x        = (fs, x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a compact one:

```
fill :: Traversable t => t (Maybe a) -> [a] -> Maybe (t a)
fill = evalStateT . traverse foo where
  foo x = maybe empty pure x <|> StateT uncons
```